# Magento: How to implement this join?

Tags: magento, join

This is my query:

```
select * from sales_flat_order sfo join sales_flat_order_payment sfop on sfo.entity_id = sfop.parent_id and sfo.status = 'some status' and sfop.method = 'some method'
```

I tried to follow this the official tutorial (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento), but did not manage to get it to work.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
/** @var $orderCollection Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection */
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
$orderCollection->join(array('p' => 'sales/order_payment'), 'main_table.entity_id=p.parent_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('p.method', 'some method')
                ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status', 'some status');
```

Comment: This gives me an exception: Cannot retrieve entity config: sales/Array' in app\Mage.php:550

Any ideas?

Comment: I am using Magento 1.4 by the way, maybe this helps?